# Sequelize - nested associations query just retrieve 1 array data?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, associations

I have a model with multiple chained association as follows :

`Pricing(hasMany) -> Item(hasMany) -> AT_PricingItem`

I'm trying to retreive **Pricing** rows with their associated **Item** & **AT_PricingItem** as a result like :

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "pricing_no": "PC-001",
        "name": "Promo 2020",
        "start_date": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "end_date": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "publish": true,
        "createdAt": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Item 1",
                "item_pricing": [
                    {
                        "ref_item_id": 1,
                        "ref_pricing_id": 1,
                        "start_qty": 1,
                        "end_qty": 10,
                        "price": 1000
                    },
                    {
                        "ref_item_id": 1,
                        "ref_pricing_id": 1,
                        "start_qty": 11
                        "end_qty": 20
                        "price": 900
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For the moment, I achieved to get a result like this (just 1 array data) :

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "pricing_no": "PC-001",
        "name": "Promo 2020",
        "start_date": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "end_date": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "publish": true,
        "createdAt": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-11T08:00:39.476Z",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Item 1",
                "item_pricing": [
                    {
                        "ref_item_id": 1,
                        "ref_pricing_id": 1,
                        "start_qty": 1
                        "end_qty": 10
                        "price": 1000
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My associate models as follows:

**Pricing.js**:

```
    T_Pricing.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here

        T_Pricing.belongsToMany(models.T_ProductItems, {
            through: 'AT_PricingItemDetails',
            foreignKey: 'ref_pricing_id',
            as: 'items'
        });  
    };
```

**Item.js**:

```
    T_ProductItems.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        T_ProductItems.belongsToMany(models.T_Pricing, {
            through: 'AT_PricingItemDetails',
            foreignKey: 'ref_item_id',
            as: 'pricing'
        });

        T_ProductItems.hasMany(models.AT_PricingItemDetails, {
            foreignKey: 'ref_item_id',
            as: 'item_pricing'
        });
      };
```

**AT_PricingItem.js**:

```
AT_PricingItemDetails.associate = function(models) {
        AT_PricingItemDetails.belongsTo(models.T_Pricing, {
            foreignKey: 'ref_pricing_id',
        })

        AT_PricingItemDetails.belongsTo(models.T_ProductItems, {
            foreignKey: "ref_item_id",
        })
      };
```

My Query as follow :

```
Pricing.findOne({
        where: {
          id: id,
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: Item,
            as: "items",
            attributes: ["id","name"],
            include: [
              {
                model: AT_Item,
                as:'item_pricing',
                attributes: ["ref_pricing_id","ref_item_id","start_qty","end_qty","price"],
              }
            ],
            through: {
              attributes: []
            },
          },
        ],
        subQuery: false
      });
```

In SQL Output:

```
SELECT "T_Pricing"."id",
 "T_Pricing"."pricing_no",
 "T_Pricing"."name",
 "T_Pricing"."start_date",
 "T_Pricing"."end_date",
 "T_Pricing"."publish",
 "items"."id" AS "items.id",
 "items"."name" AS "items.name",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."ref_pricing_id" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.ref_pricing_id",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."ref_item_id" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.ref_item_id",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."start_qty" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.start_qty",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."end_qty" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.end_qty",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."price" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.price",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."createdAt" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.createdAt",
 "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."updatedAt" AS "items.AT_PricingItemDetails.updatedAt",
 "items->item_pricing"."ref_item_id" AS "items.item_pricing.ref_item_id",
 "items->item_pricing"."ref_pricing_id" AS "items.item_pricing.ref_pricing_id",
 "items->item_pricing"."price" AS "items.item_pricing.price" FROM "T_Pricing" AS "T_Pricing" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "AT_PricingItemDetails" AS "items->AT_PricingItemDetails" INNER JOIN "T_ProductItems" AS "items" ON "items"."id" = "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."ref_item_id") ON "T_Pricing"."id" = "items->AT_PricingItemDetails"."ref_pricing_id" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "AT_PricingItemDetails" AS "items->item_pricing" ON "items"."id" = "items->item_pricing"."ref_item_id" 
 WHERE "T_Pricing"."id" = '1'
```

when i try it query in sql, it returns data correctly, but when trying it in sequelize it only gets 1 array of data, is there something wrong with my association model?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I outsmarted it with raw queries because in Sequelize there were still limitations at that time

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you can try to set subQuery true

because Sequelize will use 'limit 1' at last in the sql if you use findOne method.

or you can try to use findAll and then get the first one